# Setup Tiny-Slider in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I'm trying to use tiny-slider in my Angular 9 project. I was following [this](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider#usage) guide.

My component looks like this:

```
import { tns } from "../../../../../node_modules/tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider"
... 
ngOnInit(): void {
  tns({
    container: '.my-slider',
    items: 3,
    slideBy: 'page',
    autoplay: true
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="my-slider">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
```

I get those errors:

1. Can't find .my-slider tiny-slider.js:159:33
2. ERROR TypeError: options.container.children is undefined
   tns tiny-slider.js:166

So apparently it can not find the dom element? Any idea how to get it working under Angular.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ngOnInit()` Lifecycle Hook the actual html DOM elements are not available yet. You need to use the `ngAfterViewInit()` instead. Just implement the `AfterViewInit` interface in your component. like so:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    tns(...)
  }
}
```